# How does anomaly inflow work in terms of the eta invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, partition-function, quantum-anomalies, chern-simons-theory

I'm trying to understand the non-perturbative picture of anomaly inflow, mainly following these two articles by Witten and Yonekura: 
[1] - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.08775.pdf , 
[2] - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01873.pdf .

Let's start from the basic case when we consider a massive fermion in a d+1-dimensional manifold $Y$ s.t. $\partial Y = W$. At this point we put a boundary condition $\mathrm{L}$, which requires to have only chiral modes living on the boundary $W$. Here the chirality operator is defined by $\gamma^\tau$ ($\tau$ being the perpendicular direction to $W$).
From my understanding, considering only the perturbative picture of the system, we have that the partition function of the whole system is
$$Z_{blk+bnd} = Z_{bnd}\,e^{-iCS(g,A)}\overset{?}{=} \text{Det}\mathcal{D}_W^+\,e^{-iCS(g,A)},$$
where the first is the contribution due to the boundary theory (let's write it as $\text{Det}\mathcal{D}_W^+$), while the second is the Cherns-Simons that appear by integrating out the massive fermion in the bulk. We then find that the sum of the two contributions is anomaly-free, because the lack of gauge invariance of one term is compensated by the other. Is this correct?

We then go to the full picture, and from what the authors say, the full partition function is
$$Z_{blk+bnd}=|\text{Det}\mathcal{D}_W^+| e^{-i\pi \eta_Y}.$$
Essentially the modulus appear (looking at section 2.3 of [1]) because they defined $\psi_{\pm}$ in such a way that $\mathcal{D}_W \psi_{a,\pm} = \lambda_a \psi_{a,\mp}$, with $\lambda_a$ the positive root of the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{D}_W^2$. But then what about $\eta$? If we look at the full non-perturbative picture it should replace the role that the CS terms has in the formula above. But then is the formula above still anomaly-free?
I know I'm missing something important, thanks in advance.